# I'm trying to validate a form but the error with a message and header() won't work

Tags: php, forms

I've looked at other similar threads and the answers to them won't work for me. I've also been down-voted and a question removed for being too vague before, I hope it doesn't happen this time as I am trying to be specific. If there is something wrong with my question please tell me instead of simply just down-voting.

I am trying to make a contact form with back-end php validation. I will upgrade the HTML form to include front-end validation when I have the back-end validation working as I ultimately want both.

The contact form itself works with the mail() function however the validation won't work for some reason. I want it so that if a field is left blank it will post the notice of "All fields are required" and if the email field does not have an at-sign (@) it will display "Email must have an at-sign (@)".

To do this I have the HTML form inputs with the specified names and then in the PHP I have the validation which includes the 'header("Location: email-form2.php");' to redirect back to the same page if the form fields are not correct. However no matter what I try the redirect with the error does not happen and it simply directs to the action page of 'email-action.php', sends the email and then is complete.

What am I doing wrong that the validation doesn't work?

Here is the 'email-form2.php' code:

```
<?php 
session_start();

    if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['message']) ) {
        if ( strlen($_POST['name']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['email']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['subject']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['message']) < 1) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = "All fields are required";
            header("Location: email-form2.php");
            return;
        }   

        elseif (strpos($_POST['email'], '@' ) == false) {
            $_SESSION['error'] = "Email must have an at-sign (@)";
            header("Location: email-form2.php");
            return;
        } 
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>Email Tester</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <?php

        if ( isset($_SESSION['error']) ) {
            echo('<p style="color: red;">'.$_SESSION['error']."</p>\n");
            unset($_SESSION['error']);
            }
        ?>
        <form action="email-action.php" method="POST">
            <label for="name">Enter your name: </label><br>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
            <label for="email">Enter your email: </label><br>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
            <label for="subject">Subject:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject"><br>
            <label for="message">Enter your message:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="message" name="message"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The 'email-action.php' file is in the same folder, here is the code:

```
 <?php

        $to = "example@example.com";
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


        ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>Email Tester</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Email Sent!</h1>
        <?php 
        if ( isset($_SESSION['error']) ) {
            echo('<p style="color: red;">'.$_SESSION['error']."</p>\n");
            unset($_SESSION['error']);
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you are not getting any error or warning, let's start with turning them on. `ini_set('display_error','On');error_reporting(E_ALL);` Now let's see what error you are getting.

Comment: `<form action="email-action2.php"` will fix your problem. You send your form to another page `email-action.php`

Comment: @Ibu These are the only ini_set settings I see in my PHP ini file, I don't see others. Is one of these it?: ; per request settings. can ini_set, .htaccess etc
xcache.cacher = On
xcache.stat   = On
xcache.optimizer = Off

[xcache.coverager]
; enabling this feature will impact performance
; enabled only if xcache.coverager == On && xcache.coveragedump_directory == "non-empty-value"

; per request settings. can ini_set, .htaccess etc
; enable coverage data collecting and xcache_coverager_start/stop/get/clean() functions
xcache.coverager = Off
xcache.coverager_autostart = On

Comment: @alex I don't have an 'email-action2.php' file

Comment: 'email-form2.php' is posting to "email-action.php" where is the latter?

Comment: @smith I have edited my post now to include the 'email-action.php' file. It is in the same folder as the 'email-form2.php'.

Comment: After `header()` use `exit` instead of return. And when your first condition fails, no redirect happens. The logic is incorrect.

Comment: @ibu the exit() doesn't work either. What part of the logic is incorrect? Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: the variable checking at the top of 'email-form2.php' should not be on the page you post to (email-action.php), the post variables will never exist on email-form2.php

Comment: If you don't have it why did you write **Here is the 'email-form2.php' code:** and **'header("Location: email-form2.php");** ?

Comment: @smith that's strange as in another folder I have it works exactly like this without a problem, only in this one it doesn not work. However, I have now moved the validation code to the 'email-action.php' file and it works now...I'm happy but also confused as to why it does work in one file and not another...

Comment: @Alex in your first post you wrote 'email-ACTION2.php' I do not have that file. Only 'email-FORM2.php' and 'email-ACTION.php'

Comment: @NiallTuohy I've got you. Yes I've made a mistake when typed in rush. But the idea is the same you need to post form data to the php file where you validate your values, and then you can either output errors or execute the action you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I said in comment

```
 <form action="email-form2.php"
```

in html form of `email-form2.php` will fix your problem.

Comment: but his mail sending is in the other file, so its not that simple, the code need to be moved, either one or 2 files is fine, but in either case there's more to do than just what you posted

Comment: @smith PO is about missing error message but to create an application for the author

Comment: why bother answering if you dont actully want to help?

Comment: @smith on SO we do not help that way you expect. But I feel an know, if OP will understand my answer - hr will be able to fix his application one day.

Comment: @Alex as i mentioned in a comment, in your first post you wrote 'email-ACTION2.php' I do not have that file. Only 'email-FORM2.php' and 'email-ACTION.php'.

Comment: @NiallTuohy oh, sorry, I see. I've mixed some words! You are right. Check updated answer.

Comment: Ahhh I now see the issue. Between both Alex and Smith's comments the issue is now clear. I was working from another file I have but the 'action' in the HTML form was omitted, therefore defaulting to directing back onto the same page where the POST information was then received and then the header was triggered to redirect elsewhere. What I had was to go to another page, therefore not directing back on itself to trigger the POST data. Whew, that one really got me. Thanks for all the help everyone!! Stack Overflow rocks!